# Not able to write logs to my log file

Tags: java, maven, logging

I have created a rest service project with Maven running on Windows.
I want to write the logs to the file using Apache Log.

I have already done the following steps:

1) Created log4j.xml to config folder

```
<appender class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" name="custom">
        <param value="C:/Users/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.4.RELEASE/messenger/mylogs.log" name="File"/>
        <param value="10MB" name="MaxFileSize"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param value="%d{ISO8601} wha? %5p [%t] %-20c{1} - %m%n" name="ConversionPattern"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>


    <logger name="org.rastogi">
        <level value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="custom"/>
    </logger>
```

2) Added log4j.xml to resource folder.

3) Added config folder to Java build path.

4) Added following entry to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Still, logs has not been generated. Please could you help me on what steps are wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Add the code of the main class you are using to print to the logger

Comment: Btw, the log4j2.xml file is missing the configuration tag. I think it is just a copy-paste error but you should still upload the complete file